# How to call inner function inside composable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `suspend` inner function inside a composable but it throws a compile time error stating that the method name cannot be resolved. Why is it not working?

Comment: Could you share your snippets?

Comment: Have you declared the nested function at the top, that is before the place where it's called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call a `suspend` function inside of a composable function you have two options:

- Use `LaunchedEffect` block;
- or use a `CoroutineScope` object, which you can get using `rememberCoroutineScope`.

Something like this:

```
@Composable
fun YourComposable() {
    suspend fun innerFunc() { 
        // your code
    }
    // If you just need to call this function in the first composition
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        innerFunc()
    }
    
    // But if you need to call in response of 
    // an event you should use coroutineScope
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Button(onClick = { 
        scope.launch { 
            innerFunc()
        }
    }) {
        Text("Button")
    }
}
```